# How to add hasRecordId into my existing lightning component code?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, controller

I am pretty new to coding and need some help on how to add hasRecordId into my existing JS controller and Apex code. I need my Opportunity Id to automatically populate the recordId that the lightning component button was actioned from. Please help!

JS:

```
  updateFields: function(component, event, helper) {
    var updateId = [];
    var getAllId = component.find("boxPack");
    var recordId = component.get('v.recordId')
    
    if(! Array.isArray(getAllId)){
        if (getAllId.get("v.value") == true) {
            updateId.push(getAllId.get("v.text"));

     } 

       }else{
        
        for (var i = 0; i < getAllId.length; i++) {
            if (getAllId[i].get("v.value") == true) {
                updateId.push(getAllId[i].get("v.text"));
            }
        }
    } 

    var action = component.get('c.updateRecord');
    action.setParams({lstRecordId:updateId});

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            console.log(state);

            $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
            $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire()
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},  
      })
```

APEX:

```
    @AuraEnabled
public static void updateRecord(List <String> lstRecordId) {
    
    List<Opportunity> lstUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
    
    for(Opportunity Opp : [SELECT Id, Name, SyncedQuoteId, RecordTypeId, Trip_File_LEAD__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN : lstRecordId]){
    lstUpdate.add(Opp);
    }
    
    
     if(lstUpdate.size() > 0){
        update lstUpdate;
    }
      if(lstUpdate.size() >0)
        {
                                
            List<Quote> lstQuoteResult = new List<Quote>();
            
            List<Quote> lstQuote = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, IsDeleted, Name, CurrencyIsoCode, CreatedDate, CreatedById, LastModifiedDate, 
                                    LastModifiedById, SystemModstamp, LastViewedDate, LastReferencedDate, OpportunityId, Pricebook2Id, 
                                    ContactId, QuoteNumber, IsSyncing, ShippingHandling, Tax, Status, ExpirationDate, Description, 
                                    Subtotal, TotalPrice, LineItemCount, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode, 
                                    BillingCountry, BillingLatitude, BillingLongitude, BillingGeocodeAccuracy, BillingAddress, 
                                    ShippingStreet, ShippingCity, ShippingState, ShippingPostalCode, ShippingCountry, ShippingLatitude, 
                                    ShippingLongitude, ShippingGeocodeAccuracy, ShippingAddress, QuoteToStreet, QuoteToCity, QuoteToState, 
                                    QuoteToPostalCode, QuoteToCountry, QuoteToLatitude, QuoteToLongitude, QuoteToGeocodeAccuracy, 
                                    QuoteToAddress, AdditionalStreet, AdditionalCity, AdditionalState, AdditionalPostalCode, 
                                    AdditionalCountry, AdditionalLatitude, AdditionalLongitude, AdditionalGeocodeAccuracy, 
                                    AdditionalAddress, BillingName, ShippingName, QuoteToName, AdditionalName, Email, Phone, 
                                    Fax, ContractId, AccountId, Discount, GrandTotal, CanCreateQuoteLineItems, Airline__c, 
                                    Milestone__c, Milest__c, Milestone_Deposit_Date__c, Final_Deposit_Balance_Due__c, 
                                    FInal_Deposit_Balance_Amount__c, Start_Date__c, Product_Interested_In__c, Check_In_Date__c, 
                                    Check_Out_Date__c, Old_Quote__c, Price_Book_Name__c, Sent_to_Customer_Date__c, Price_Per_Person__c, 
                                    Airfare_Required__c, Airfare_Amount__c, Insurance_Required__c, Insurance_Amount__c, Misc_Add_On__c, 
                                    Misc_Add_On_Price__c, Overall_Grand_Total__c, Discount_Applied__c, Per_Person__c, Quotation_Total__c, 
                                    Amount__c, Departing__c, Arrival__c, Departure_Date__c, Arrival_Date__c, Flight__c, Flight_Details__c, 
                                    Insurance_From__c, Insurance_To__c, Number_of_Nights__c, Misc_Add_On_Required__c, Passenger_Names__c, 
                                    Checkout_checkin__c, Final_Payment_Due_Date__c
                                    FROM Quote
                                    WHERE OpportunityId = : '0065500000HMAr5AAH']; //Replace custom Id with a line to query hasRecordId (the record the lightning component button was actioned from.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your component is on a Lightning Record Page then you can use `force:hasRecordId` interface.
[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasRecordId/documentation)

For eg: In your aura component `.cmp` file you can add like this:

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId" access="global">
```

And then in your controller or helper layer you can access the record Id by:

```
component.get('v.recordId')
```

and you can get the recordId of the Object.

For passing recordId to backend just do this:

Add another parameter to your `setParams`

```
    var action = component.get('c.updateRecord');
    action.setParams({lstRecordId:updateId, oppRecordId:recordId});
```

Change your apex method to accept those params:

```
public static void updateRecord(List <String> lstRecordId, String oppRecordId) {
```

then change you query to this `WHERE OpportunityId = :oppRecordId`

Comment: Hi @NagendraSingh , thank you for your reply. I have done above, I am just unsure how to add this into my existing Apex code. Could you please help? Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to pass this to Apex from UI?

Comment: Yes I do! I am just unsure how to add this into my apex so that my Opportunity Id equals the hasRecordId (please see code above). ' WHERE OpportunityId = : '0065500000HMAr5AAH']; //Add in line to query hasRecordId (the record the lightning component button was actioned from)'

Comment: I have update the answer, but you were already passing one param, where did you face challenge to pass the second param?

Comment: Thank you so much that code works perfectly! I just had an issue with incorporating the param into my existing code as I am quiet new to coding. You have been of great help!