# Help with filtering a list of records on a Lightning Component!

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, community

I am new to coding and need some assistance on adding in a parameter to my lightning component button on my Opportunity which displays only the records that have the same Trip_File_LEAD__c(which is a lookup field for a custom object I created called Trip File). I just need some assistance in writing this. Any help is much appreciated! Below is my current code:

APEX:

```
   public with sharing class UpdateExistingPaxController {

 @AuraEnabled
  public static List <Opportunity> fetchOpportunity() {

    return [SELECT Id, Name, Trip_File_LEAD__c
            FROM Opportunity Limit 30];
    
}
```

Lightning Component:

```
  <aura:component controller="UpdateExistingPaxController"
            implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >

<aura:attribute name="OpportunityList" type="List" access="global" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.loadOpportunities}"/>
<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.loadOpportunities}" />

<div class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-end"> 
    <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.updateFields}">Update</button>
</div>


<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
    <thead>
        <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
            <th style="width:3.25rem;" class="slds-text-align--right">
                <div class="slds-form-element">
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <label class="slds-checkbox">
                            <!--header checkbox for select all-->
                            <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="box3" change="{!c.selectAll}"/>
                            <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
                            <span class="slds-form-element__label text"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <span class="slds-truncate">Name</span>      
            </th>
            <th>
                <span class="slds-truncate">Trip File Record</span>
            </th>
           
            </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.OpportunityList}" var="Opp">
            <tr>
                <td scope="row" class="slds-text-align--right" style="width:3.25rem;">
                    <div class="slds-form-element">
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                            <label class="slds-checkbox">
                                <ui:inputCheckbox text="{!Opp.Id}" aura:id="boxPack" value=""/>
                                <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
                                <span class="slds-form-element__label text"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td scope="row">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!Opp.Name}"><a>{!Opp.Name}</a></div>
                </td>
                <td scope="row">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!Opp.Trip_File_LEAD__c}">{!Opp.Trip_File_LEAD__c}</div>
                </td>
                 </tr>
        </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>
</table>
     </aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
    ({

loadOpportunities: function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get('c.fetchOpportunity');

          action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {

            component.set('v.OpportunityList', response.getReturnValue());
            component.find("box3").set("v.value", false);
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Comment: So if I have 4 record, two records with `Trip_File_LEAD__c` as `123` and other two records with `Trip_File_LEAD__c` as `1234`, then what should it show? What is the input parameter to check if `Trip_File_LEAD__c` is same? Is there a filter box somewhere in UI?

Comment: @NagendraSingh Hi Nagendra, so if you have 4 records with the Trip_File_LEAD__c as 123 and the record the Lightning component has been actioned from also has the Trip_File_LEAD__c as 123, it should only display those 4 records as they are related to eachother through the Trip_File_LEAD__c. I don't have a filter box on my UI at the moment, I was just hoping that I could query the Trip_File_LEAD__c field from the hasRecordId, and that would bring up the related records with the same Trip_File_LEAD__c. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes if you already have the component on a record page then you can use `hasRecordId`, I think I have already answered this type of question here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/328837/how-to-add-hasrecordid-into-my-existing-lightning-component-code

Comment: @NagendraSingh Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I just added the recordId into my controller and Apex as follows.

```
    ({

loadOpportunities: function(component, event, helper) {
    var recordId = component.get('v.recordId')
    var action = component.get('c.fetchOpportunity');
     action.setParams({oppRecordId:recordId});

          action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {

            component.set('v.OpportunityList', response.getReturnValue());
            component.find("box3").set("v.value", false);
        }
    });
```

Apex:

```
   public with sharing class UpdateExistingPaxController {

 @AuraEnabled
public static List <Opportunity> fetchOpportunity(String oppRecordId) {

    return [SELECT Id, Name, Trip_File_LEAD__c
            FROM Opportunity
            WHERE Lead_PAX__c = :oppRecordId];
    
}
```